# How to properly configure dependencies in Subdirs project?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

There are several ways how to go about dependencies in Qt Creator. With regular projects there is a dependency tab under the Project configuration. With `Subdirs` project there is a `.depends` parameter one can give to each project. [DOCS](https://wiki.qt.io/SUBDIRS_-_handling_dependencies) However `Subdirs` project can contain other `Subdirs` projects and the dependencies can thus span across these with a project under sub-sub-project depends on another that is in different sub-sub-project:

```
Master Subdirs
L--- Subdirs 1
     L--- Project 1
L--- Subdirs 2
     L--- Project 2 //depends on Project 1
```

There are two issues with this setup:

1) One cannot set the dependencies in `Master Subdirs` because neither `Project 2` or `Project 1` are known to it (similarly for `Subdirs 2`). The only thing that can be set is whether `Subdirs 2` depends on `Subdirs 1` but that will not help if there are mutual dependencies.

2) When building `Project 2` on its own it does not know about its dependencies set in the `Subdirs` project and since projects in `Subdirs` cannot have regular dependencies set in Project tab one cannot build it automatically and must either build everything or build the dependencies manually before the actual project.

Are there any solutions to these problems? No. 1 can be solved with not using child `Subdirs` but no. 2 is still an issue regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assessment is basically correct.

1) You can only set dependencies in a subdirs .pro file between projects that are children of this subdirs .pro file, so to make `Project 2` dependent on `Project 1` you either need to make `Subdirs 2` dependent on `Subdirs 1` or get rid of the child subdirs.

2) To build `Project 2` while regarding the dependency on `Project 1` you either have to build `Master Subdirs`, or, if you opened `Project 1` and `Project 2` as individual projects in Qt Creator, you need to configure the dependency in the `Dependencies` tab under the project configuration for `Project 2`.

Comment: Alternatively you could look into using a more advanced meta build system such as `CMake`, which, I think, tracks dependencies on build targets